# How to convert Date in moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am new to Moment js, and I have date in this format:
`Mon Jul 14 00:00:00 EDT 2014`, and I want to convert this date to `MMM DD HH:mm Z` format, can some one please help me in doing this?

I am able to convert to required format of my date when I specify with out time zone, but when I specify time zone it is showing wrong time, like below:

```
Jul 14 09:30 +05:30
```

If I use this code :

```
var dateStr = "Mon Jul 14 00:00:00 EDT 2014";
var momentDateFormatted = moment(dateStr).format("MMM DD HH:mm Z");
```

it is showing wrong time.

If I use this code :

```
var dateStr = "Mon Jul 14 00:00:00 2014";
var momentDateFormatted = moment(dateStr).format("MMM DD HH:mm Z");
```

by removing `EDT` (time Zone): it is showing correctly, why? Is there any way that I can pass time zone and get it correctly?

Comment: To reliably parse a string, you **must** tell the parser the format, or conform to a format you know it parses correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use moment.js to convert date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737509/use-moment-js-to-convert-date-format)

Answer (score 3):

Here is some working tested code on js fiddle I created
http://jsfiddle.net/markd116/kj5nzz4w/

```
var dateStr = "Mon Jul 14 00:00:00 EDT 2014";
var momentDateFormatted = moment(dateStr).format("MMM DD HH:mm Z");
jQuery("div").text(momentDateFormatted);
```

Outputs
`Jul 14 00:00 -04:00`

Answer (score 1):

Found this code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.date').each(function (index, dateElem) {
        var $dateElem = $(dateElem);
        var formatted = moment($dateElem.text(), 'MM-DD-YYYY').format('MMMM D');
        $dateElem.text(formatted);
    })
});​
```

Here: [Use moment.js to convert date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737509/use-moment-js-to-convert-date-format)

Also, here are format types:

```
2013-02-08T09            # An hour time part separated by a T
2013-02-08 09            # An hour time part separated by a space
2013-02-08 09:30         # An hour and minute time part
2013-02-08 09:30:26      # An hour, minute, and second time part
2013-02-08 09:30:26.123  # An hour, minute, second, and millisecond time part
2013-02-08 24:00:00.000  # hour 24, minute, second, millisecond equal 0 means next day at midnight

2013-02-08  # A calendar date part
2013-W06-5  # A week date part
2013-039    # An ordinal date part

2013-02-08 09+07:00            # +-HH:mm
2013-02-08 09-0100             # +-HHmm
2013-02-08 09Z                 # Z
2013-02-08 09:30:26.123+07:00  # +-HH:mm
```

With more examples at: http://momentjs.com/docs/

Hope this answers your question

Comment: if  I give moment('Mon Jul 14 00:00:00 EDT 2014', EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy) like this I am getting an exception saying invalid date, can you help me how to convert this kind of dates.

Comment: You don't need the second argument.  Look at @med116 's answer/JFiddle it uses the correct syntax... also if his/her code works and you don't mind, give them a +1 for me, I don't have enough rep. to do so